# Getting error when i try to build image by trigger in kubernetes gcp

Tags: docker, image, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, artifact

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/digidoc-uat/locations/asia-south1/clusters/digidocuatfe".

Answer (score 2):

The two required steps are:

1. `gcloud auth login`
2. Setting up authentication for docker, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication)

`gcloud auth configure docker asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev`.

The exact command for your repo can also be seen by logging in to the Google Cloud console, entering the repo and clicking on `SETUP INSTRUCTIONS`
[image]

Comment: i tried that and when i again push got image name not found

Comment: @RahulChhabra what are the commands you use to push the image? You need to tag it and then push. `docker tag "${local_tag}" "${repository}${local_tag}" && docker push "${repository}${local_tag}"`

Comment: sudo docker push asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/tes-dev/testdoc-art:imagename

Comment: So if your local image is `image:tag` and your repo full name is `asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/tes-dev` then you should run `docker tag image:tag asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/tes-dev/image:tag && docker push asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/tes-dev/image:tag`.

Comment: imagetag: testrahul
repo:asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/tes-dev/testdoc-art

can you please provide me push comand

Comment: @RahulChhabra Edit your question with new details - do not use comments.